# Метод возвращает новую высоту

Tags: javascript, функции

Создать объект, с полем высота и методом "увеличения на один", который возвращает новую высоту.

У меня такой пример, но это неправильно, как сделать правильно?

```js
const step = {
   height: function () {
       return this;
   },
   inc: function () {
       return height + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: сразу видно вместо height - this.height

Answer (score 1):

```js
const step = {
  height: 0,

  inc: function() {
    return ++this.height
  }
}

console.log(step.inc());
console.log(step.inc());
console.log(step.height);
```

Comment: А если мне надо задавать значение высоты в консоли?

Comment: ну так и задавайте `step.height = 100500;`

Comment: и коли уж `const`, то наверное: `const step = { height: 0, get inc() { return ++this.height; } };`, ну и соответственно просто вызывать `step.inc`

Comment: @MedvedevDev да, у меня тоже был соблазн сделать геттер, но решил, что это будет не совсем соответствовать формулировке вопроса. :)